# TLS 1.0 & 1.1 support by browsers stops in March, what will happen if I keep using it?

Tags: tls

In March most browsers will stop supporting TLS 1.0 & 1.1 my website already uses 1.2 but some external apis still use TLS 1.0. What will happen with the requests to those apis? Will they keep working as they are or will there be some sort of error?

Comment: Are the clients that consume your API browser-based?  If not, nothing will happen when browsers stop supporting TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1.

Comment: The api is called from the browser @mti2935

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The requests to those APIs will fail.

This is because browsers will try to do a handshake with the API server, and only accept servers who support TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3. If those servers don't support either of those, the client will reject the connection.

As a result, you have several options on how to proceed now, each with varying pro's and con's.

#### Request the API providers to upgrade to TLS 1.2 or 1.3

This is the recommended approach, as it actually results in better security for every endpoint. The obvious downside is that you can't force the providers to do this, so you may have to look into alternatives.

#### Replace the API

If the providers of the API do not care about maintaining their service, then a valid strategy is to find someone who does. While the migration from one API to another is indeed a lot of work, the upside is that you work with a more stable API. This assumes that you *can* migrate to a different API. If the API you are consuming is the sole provider of the data or service you need, then you must find a different option.

#### Build a Proxy for the API

Simply put, your website provides a server that speaks TLS 1.2 and/or TLS 1.3, and simply relays all API requests and responses to the client. This may be a feasible solution, depending on the amount of clients requesting the API. It could also be used as a temporary workaround while the above mentioned API providers fix their TLS configuration.

#### Require users to use legacy browsers

This is an approach I am not a fan of, because it makes everybody less safe. However, in small environments, this could be a feasible quick-and-dirty (with the emphasis on dirty) workaround to keep things working one more day.

Comment: While technically valid, I must strongly advise against the options 2 and 3, because they decrease security and because these APIs do not seem to be properly maintained and will likely stop working soon. Dependencies on deprecated APIs or libraries should be fixed as soon as possible to reduce the cost of switching when the piece of software finally breaks (not **if**, but **when**). The OP should see this process as an opportunity to refactor its web application by using interfaces that will allow to replace dependencies more easily in the future.

Comment: @A.Hersean This assumes that the API is indeed replacable. And if that is the case, then indeed going for a better API is a valid and even recommended solution. But when writing this answer, I assumed that the API provider has a monopoly on the data and/or functionality.

Comment: In this case I hope someone will pray for the poor OP's soul, because indeed the OP would have to use solution 2, or someone else's god forbid, solution 3.